# meaning of this code: return self.desk[number]![alpha]

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, option-type, subscript

please help me understand this part of the code. Why is `!` located between two brackets `[]![]` in this expression: `self.desk[number]![alpha]`?

```
class GameDesk {
    var desk : [Int: [String: Chessman]] = [:]

    init() {
        for i in 1...8 {
            desk[i] = [:]
        }
    }

    subscript(alpha: String, number: Int) -> Chessman? {
        get {
            return self.desk[number]![alpha]
        }
        set {
            if let chessman = newValue {
                self.setChessman(chess: chessman, coordinates: (alpha, number))
            } else {
                self.desk[number]![alpha] = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func setChessman(chess: Chessman, coordinates: (String, Int)){
        let rowRange = 1...8
        let colRange = "A"..."Z"
        if(rowRange.contains(coordinates.1) && colRange.contains(coordinates.0)) {
            self.desk[coordinates.1]![coordinates.0] = chess
            chess.setCoordinates(char: coordinates.0, num: coordinates.1)
        } else {
            print("Coordinates out of range")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A dictionary returns an optional (`nil` if the key doesn't exist). In your case the correct syntax is even `self.desk[number]?[alpha]`

Comment: Using a dictionary here is a pretty strange choice, given that the keys are consecutive integers. This could have just used an array, with `desk = (1...8).map { _ in [:] }`, then accessed with `self.desk[number - 1][alpha]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand the meaning, but I don't understand the syntax of "desk[number]![alpha]"

Answer (score 1):

`desk` is a dictionary with a key of `Int` and a value which is another dictionary that itself has a key of `String` and a value of `Chessman`. The `subscript` function implements setting or getting a piece by the row number and column string. A lookup in a dictionary returns an optional value (the key might not exist) but this code is (somewhat dangerously) assuming that it will never be called with an invalid `number` and is force unwrapping the lookup with the `!`. That makes the result non-optional and another dictionary lookup is performed to find the chess piece at the `alpha`. That can also be optional which is why the method returns an optional. This also means the code could have used `?` as @vadian said in a comment.

That answers your question, but it’s worth mentioning that nested dictionaries is not a very good way to implement a chess board. A two dimensional array would be simpler and more efficient. But that’s a whole separate other question…

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for your recommendations, I am very grateful to you!